# SQL UPDATE with JOIN for WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hopefully an easy question: I have two `sql` tables `Items` and `BillOfMaterials`

`Items` has fields `ItemID` and `ItemCategory`
`BillOfMaterials` has fields `ItemID` and `ComponentItemID`

How can I do an `UPDATE` on `BillOfMaterials` to change the `ComponentItemID` where the `ItemID` has a certain category? e.g.

```
UPDATE BillOfMaterials
SET ComponentItemID = dbo.GetNewItemID(ComponentItemID)
WHERE ItemCategory = 1 <-- Magic join here to pull in ItemCategory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Comment: Be careful of scalar functions. They can be serious performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE b
SET ComponentItemID = dbo.GetNewItemID(ComponentItemID)
FROM BillOfMaterials b
INNER JOIN Items I on I.ItemID = b.ComponentItemID
WHERE i.ItemCategory = 1
```

Comment: That seems to have done ALL records, not just that that are Category 1

Comment: Ahh, ignore me, I need to join against b.ComponentItemID not b.ItemID but thats fine. Thanks Becuzz